# how can I sum on a function in a loop in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

We have a function that receives 4 variables and returns one int result.
We would like to use this function for every record in my table while those 4 variable are taken from each record.

How should I solve it?

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.occupiedDaysPerListingFunction(@CheckIn date, @CheckOut date, @Email varchar(80), @Title varchar(50))
            RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @nightsInRange int  
    select @nightsInRange= (CASE  
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) >0 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 <0 THEN 100
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) >0 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 >0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckOut)
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) >0 and DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) <100 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 >0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,@CheckOut)
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) >0 and DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) <100 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 <0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate())+100
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) <0 THEN 0
END)
FROM [dbo].[ORDERS] o
        WHERE o.[E-mail] = @Email and o.[title]=@Title
        RETURN @nightsInRange
end
```

[image]

Comment: The title of your question mentions "sum", but that doesn't appear in the question. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

**Cursor** is just a tool suitable for this task. Сursor is one of the possible options. You can also use a WHILE LOOP, CTE, etc.

```
DECLARE @iterator CURSOR
DECLARE @bufferTable TABLE 
(
    CheckIn date,
    CheckOut date,
    Email varchar(80),
    Title varchar(50)
)

SET @iterator = CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    CheckIn,
    CheckOut,
    Email,
    Title
FROM  [YourDatabase].[YourSchema].[YourTable]    

OPEN @iterator 

FETCH NEXT FROM @iterator 
INTO @bufferTable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    /* Your function comes into play */
    dbo.occupiedDaysPerListingFunction(@bufferTable.CheckIn, @bufferTable.CheckOut, @bufferTable.Email, @bufferTable.Title)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @iterator 
    INTO @bufferTable 
END; 

CLOSE @iterator
DEALLOCATE @iterator

GO
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @[Rasmus Dybkjær](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435992/rasmus-dybkj%C3%A6r)'s answer, you could narrow down the SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT InnerQueryTable.OccupiedDaysPerListing FROM 
(
    SELECT
        CheckInDate,
        CheckOutDate,
        Email,
        Title,
        dbo.occupiedDaysPerListingFunction(CheckInDate, CheckOutDate, Email, Title) AS OccupiedDaysPerListing
    FROM
        [YourDatabase].[YourSchema].[YourTable]
) AS InnerQueryTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start be ensuring that your function always returns an integer. Your current function sends a query to your [Orders] table with a filter on email and title. You should consider what would (should) happen if your [Orders] table contains multiple rows with the same email and title.

I would begin with rewriting your function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.occupiedDaysPerListingFunction(@CheckIn DATE, @CheckOut 
DATE, @Email VARCHAR(80), @Title VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nightsInRange INT = 0;
    SET @nightsInRange = (SELECT TOP 1 CASE  
        WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) >0 and     DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 <0 THEN 100
        WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) >0 and     DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100 >0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckOut)
        WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) >0 and     DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) <100 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100     >0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,@CheckOut)
        WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) >0 and     DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),@CheckIn) <100 and DATEDIFF(day,@CheckOut,getdate())+100     <0 THEN DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate())+100
        WHEN  DATEDIFF(day,@CheckIn,getdate()) <0 THEN 0
        ELSE 0
    END
    FROM [dbo].[ORDERS] o
    WHERE o.[E-mail] = @Email and o.[title]=@Title)

    RETURN @nightsInRange
END
```

This function is still not flawless, but it ensures that:
1) Your function returns a value in all cases (even if no records are found)
2) Your function does not fail due to multiple [Orders] with the same email and title

Afterwards I would call your function from a query like this:

```
SELECT
    CheckInDate,
    CheckOutDate,
    Email,
    Title,
    dbo.occupiedDaysPerListingFunction(CheckInDate, CheckOutDate, Email,     Title) AS OccupiedDaysPerListing
FROM
    [YourDatabase].[YourSchema].[YourTable]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As a rule `TOP` ought to be paired with `ORDER BY`. In this case, where any row will do, it is worth adding a comment to explain the expected behavior. Note that each instance of `GetDate()` will return a single value for all rows, but that different instances may return different values. Best practice would be to get a single value, e.g. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();`, and use the variable `@Now` throughout the  rest of the function.

Comment: Agree with your points, @HABO. These would be additional improvements of the query. In this case he would most likely want to order by an OrderDate, descending. I.e.

    `ORDER BY [OrderDate] DESC`